# Manage ads for app users

Tags: facebook-ads-api

My web app is helping small businesses create content for their business pages.
I want to add the ability for my users to promote their posts.
most of my users don't have an ads account.

I can think of two options:

1. ask them to create an ads account
2. ask them to give my user an advertiser privilege for their page and use my own ads account

is there a better, more automated solution than these two options? if not, which one is preferred?

Comment: The marketing API is designed explicitly for creating apps that manage ads on a user's behalf: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis

Answer (score 1):

You should ask them to create their own ad account.

Shared ad account owned by you woud make it impossible for your customers to choose different payment methods, currency, contact info and other. They also wouldn't be able to generate invoices, which may be crucial for business customers.

Also you won't need to handle your customers' expenses. On a shared account I can easily imagine a case where a customer is boosting posts using your app, but doesn't pay for it. In that case you would be the one to pay the Facebook, since you'd own a shared account and you couldn't leave it without money because of other customers using it.